# Python : launch a script from another script

Tags: python, process, execution

I have a Python script `script_A.py` which is executed. Inside this script, I run another script, `script_B.py`.

The thing is, `script_A.py` needs about one minute to be executed, while `script_B.py` needs about 20 minutes.

So my questions are:

- Will my `script_B` be stopped if my `script_A` stops properly (after it has finished)?
- Will my `script_B` be stopped if my `script_A` stops with an error (or a 'kill command' or anything else)?

For both questions:

- What is the solution to make the `script_B` last until it ends properly?

EDIT :

I am working on a Raspberry Pi. On script_A.py, I have something like this :

```
for i in range(0,100):
    SOME CALCULATIONS
    if i == 20:
        os.system("sudo python script_B.py")
```

The loop is taking less time than the script_B, but I am script_B to be executed at the same time...

Moreover, is there a way to know when script_B is finished ? Because only the "print" from the first script will be showed !

Comment: "Inside this script, I run another script, script_B.py." Can you show us the code for how you're doing that? There are many ways you could do this and the way you've chosen affects the answer

Comment: It depends if the script is blocking or not. Could you please show your code?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: `os.system` is blocking, it will wait until script_b finishes

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
import os 
try:
   os.system('python script_B.py')
except:
   pass
#do script a
```

If you want to do them at the same time you will need to use multithreading.